# how to pipe two to shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script, terminal

how to  cut the selected columns from the file.

Example:

```
load.sh students.csv | select.sh ‘name’ ‘school_name’
```

This will output the name and school_name columna from the loaded file to the terminal.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: @Jesse_b, Agreed. Please provide example which will be more easy. 

Is it not possible to do so in same script ?

Comment: You're thinking too much like Windows Powershell. UNIX/Linux shells don't pass objects through pipes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `csvcut` or `csvsql` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
csvcut -c name,school_name students.csv
csvsql --query 'select name, school_name from students' students.csv
```

---

Example:

```
$ cat students.csv
id,name,surname,school_name,favorite_color
1,Tom,Sawyer,Harvard,red
2,Bob,"the Builder",Oxford,orange
3,John,Sinclair,"Columbine High",blue
4,Walter,Mitty,"Thomas Jefferson High",green
5,Donald,Trump,Unknown,blue

$ csvcut -c name,school_name students.csv
name,school_name
Tom,Harvard
Bob,Oxford
John,Columbine High
Walter,Thomas Jefferson High
Donald,Unknown
```

Comment: `cvscut` would be easier, if the columns have named headers.

Comment: True... I'll add that.csvsql is good if we need some grouping/joins etc, but for such simple select you're right.